# jQuery custom UI dialog not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I am in the process of creating a little webpage based on the Periodic Table of Elements, and I'm trying to make it so that if one were to click on an element's square, a dialog box will pop up to display a list of compounds. I've ran into an issue with displaying a jQuery dialog box with a custom theme that I generated at jQuery's ThemeRoller, however - it merely appears as plain text at the top left corner, and as far as I know, I've supplied the necessary links to the associated JS and CSS files.

I did have a working version beforehand, but I also have plans on using multiple themes for the dialog box (in the efforts to make them color-coded for the squares), and now trying to implement that has essentially thrown everything for a loop. Even scanning through the various other related questions on here has proven fruitless, not to mention the link to Filament's posting in regards to using multiple themes (http://filamentgroup.com/lab/using_multiple_jquery_ui_themes_on_a_single_page/). Currently I only have one theme active.

Here is the code - I apologize for the clunky size (A table with 100+ cells is not exactly small...)

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
     <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8" />
     <title>The Periodic Table of Elements</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animate.css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3/themes/blue/jquery-ui.css">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>

     </head>

     <body>
      <h3>The Periodic Table of Elements</h3>
      <div class="container">
       <table width="100%" align="center" cellspacing="1px" cellpadding="1px">
        <tr>
         <th><p>Group<br/>Period</p></th>
         <th><p>1</p></th>
         <th><p>2</p></th>
         <th><p>3</p></th>
         <th><p>4</p></th>
         <th><p>5</p></th>
         <th><p>6</p></th>
         <th><p>7</p></th>
         <th><p>8</p></th>
         <th><p>9</p></th>
         <th><p>10</p></th>
         <th><p>11</p></th>
         <th><p>12</p></th>
         <th><p>13</p></th>
         <th><p>14</p></th>
         <th><p>15</p></th>
         <th><p>16</p></th>
         <th><p>17</p></th>
         <th><p>18</p></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td id="number"><p><b>1</b></p></td>
         <td>
             <div class="element" id="hydrogen" style="background: #6699FF;">
             <div class="number"><h6>1</h6></div>
             <div class="symbol"><h4>H</h4></div>
             <div class="weight"><h5>1.008</h5></div>
            </div>
         </td>
         <td colspan="16"><p>Click on an element square to view associated compounds:</p></td>
         <td>
             <div class="element" id="helium" style="background: #FFCC33;">
             <div class="number"><h6>2</h6></div>
             <div class="symbol"><h4>He</h4></div>
             <div class="weight"><h5>4.0026</h5></div>
            </div>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td id="number"><p><b>2</b></p></td>
         <td>
             <div class="element" id="lithium" style="background: #6699FF;">
             <div class="number"><h6>3</h6></div>
             <div class="symbol"><h4>Li</h4></div>
             <div class="weight"><h5>6.94</h5></div>
            </div>
         </td>
         <td>
             <div class="element" id="beryllium" style="background: #6699FF;">
             <div class="number"><h6>4</h6></div>
             <div class="symbol"><h4>Be</h4></div>
             <div class="weight"><h5>9.012</h5></div>
            </div>
         </td>
         <td colspan="10"></td>
         <td>
             <div class="element" id="boron" style="background: #FFCC33;">
             <div class="number"><h6>5</h6></div>
             <div class="symbol"><h4>B</h4></div>
             <div class="weight"><h5>10.81</h5></div>
            </div>
         </td>
         <!-- I edited out the rest because it went 2000 characters ABOVE the limit...
but it should supply the general idea. -->
        </tr>
       </table>
      </div>

      <div class="dialog" title="Element Info:">
        <p>Content</p>
      </div>

      <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var blue = $(".dialog");
            blue.dialog(
            {
                width: 400,
                height: 500,
                autoOpen: false,
                buttons: {
                    "OK": function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
            $(".dialog").hide();

            $(".element").click(function(){

                $(".dialog").dialog("open");
            });


        });
      </script>

     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: Based on the fact that your code is appearing as text, it implies that the jQueryUI css isn't being found.  I see you're referencing it, but is there any chance the path is messed up?

Comment: take out `$(".dialog").hide();`. Once widget is enabled parts of the widget that need to be hidden is handled internally by plugin and you have `autoOpen:false` to manage that. Always use widget API once you enable them

Comment: @Barmar I've tried checking the console, and nothing pointed to anything relating to the dialog. No idea if I'm overlooking something there. As for the path to the CSS, I have no idea. I've been looking at the paths and they appear correct in my folder hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Scott Mermelstein's theory may be correct - you're not including the libraries that you need. Here is a jsfiddle of your code using different library paths.  Your code is (minus removal of headers) untouched and is working as expected:

http://jsfiddle.net/2Cpnd/1/

External references used for the above fiddle are:

`//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js`

`//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/le-frog/jquery-ui.min.css`

`//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js`

I would suggest substituting your links from the internal files (jquery-ui.css, jquery-ui.js and jquery-1.10.2.js) to external links to see if that eliminates the issue.

Comment: Well well... that fixed the dialog box popping up. Very nice and thanks! Now to see if I can figure out how to use multiple themes without crashing it.